# How many sequences satisfy this condition?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose we have a positive integer $N > 2$ and a set $S = \{S_1, \ldots, S_K\} \subset \{1, \ldots, N\}$. How many sequences $k \in \{(a_1, \ldots, a_{N - 2}) | 1 \leq a_i \leq N\}$ of length $N - 2$ are there such that $a_i$ appears $S_j - 1$ times in the sequence for some $1 \leq j \leq K$?

My initial thought is that we can try to sum to $N - 2$ using the values $\{S_1 - 1, \ldots, S_K - 1\}$. These values will represent the counts of distinct values from 1 to $N$. We can then permute these numbers to obtain distinct sequences, but this seems like a pretty tricky route to obtain a closed form answer. A provided hint is to use the multinomial theorem but I'm having trouble seeing its application. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use exponential generating functions. To preface, we want to assign, in some form or another, a value $c_i$ to each $1 \leq i \leq N$ such that $c_i = S_j - 1$ for some $j$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^N c_i = N - 2$. This, however, ignores permutations which we'll address below.

Consider $(\sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1} a_i x^i)^N$ such that $a_i = 0$ if $i + 1 \not \in S$ else $a_i = 1$. Note that the coefficient of $x^{N - 2}$ counts the number of $N$-length sequences $(c_1, \ldots, c_N)$ such that $\sum_{i = 1}^N c_i = N - 2$ and $c_i = S_j - 1$. However, we are not counting the permutations of these sequences; e.g. (2, 0, 2) corresponds to (1, 1, 3, 3) and (1, 3, 1, 1).

To do so, we adjust our exponential generating function to $f(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{N - 1} \frac{a_i}{i!}x^i$. Our answer is thus $(N - 2)!f^N(x)[x^{N - 2}]$ where $f^N(x)[x^{N - 2}]$ is the coefficient of $x^{N - 2}$ in $f^N(x)$.